# Upload JES job using Powershell and FTP and download the response

Tags: powershell, ftp, mainframe

I'm using this script to upload a JOB on the Mainframe.

```
"open $FTPserver" | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII
$FTPusername | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
$FTPpassword | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
"quote site filetype=jes" | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
"put " + $FTPfile | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
"quit" | Out-File ftp.scr -Encoding ASCII -Append
ftp.exe -s:ftp.scr
Remove-Item ftp.scr
```

Script works great. But I would like to save this response to variable so I can download in the next step this JOB for the response. This is my targeted response:

```
250-It is known to JES as JOB24503
```

Is there a way also to hide the output text from the FTP?

Comment: Can''t you direct the output from your script to a file?

Comment: I would like to do that. :) So I can then work with JOBXXXXX.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect output to a file use the > operator.

```
ftp.exe -s:ftp.scr > ftp.out
```

I'm not a powershell guru but I do know that you can use the full .NET API which gives you access to a very sophiticated runtime. Check out [FtpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used to run FTP requests and pipe the output back to streams.